# Java InputStream reading the chracter \" instead of showing as " for html content file

Tags: java

I want to read a HTML content file which in a string format

The file content as below

```
<table class=\"relative-table\" style
```

But when I inspect in java it showing as below

```
<table class="\&quot;relative-table\&quot;" style=
```

My expectation was to as below

```
<table class="relative-table" style
```

Below is my Java code:

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\table.xml");
        Document doc;   
        try {
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file); 
            doc = Jsoup.parse(stream, null, "UTF-8", Parser.xmlParser());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Sample source file

```
<table class=\"relative-table\" style=\"width: 100.0%;\">
  <colgroup>
    <col style=\"width: 10%;\" />
    <col style=\"width: 20%;\" />
    <col style=\"width: 70%;\" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   ........
```

Comment: Why does the source file contain escaped quotes? I think this is the actual issue. The the parser represents the quotes as `&quot;` should be finde. This is handled by XML parsers.

Comment: yup correct, my source file contains escape character that the reasons of having &quot;  I want the escape characters to reach as single quotation in java. In the source it have escape characters as the string will be taken our by other methdo for string processing

Comment: In the expected output there are no backslashes. Should you perhaps use the string processing first? Also, what is the actual issue? What do you need ultimately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems that those backslashes do not belong in the **file** content. (In a java String `"... \" ... "` backslash+quote would simply represent the quote char.) Hence the quote is seen as part on an unquoted HTML attribute, and actually "repaired" as HTML/XML entity `&quot;`.

```
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\table.xml");
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    content = content.replace("\\\"", "\"");
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Document doc;   
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(bais, null, "UTF-8", Parser.xmlParser());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This ugly patch has one flaw: one cannot be sure, that not more is concerned.

Comment: Can i know what do you mean by "This ugly patch has one flaw: one cannot be sure, that not more is concerned."

Comment: There might be `\n` and `\t` written out; a search for a backslash should do.